# How do I put 2 commands in 1 button

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to put 2 commands to 1 button so I can destroy one of the commands which is only text, when a another button is pressed. But is says:

```
Play = Button(text="Play!", lambda: [f() for f in [entry, playernames]])                                                                           
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument.
```

heres the code, and it probably looks gross, but ive only been into coding for about 2 weeks.

````
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os



root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Number Guessing Game by Goasef")



#CANVAS
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#263D42", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_text(350,70,fill="white",font=("Courier", 16, "italic"), text="THE NUMBER GUESSING GAME")
canvas.create_text(68,20,fill="white",font=("Arial", 12, "italic"), text="Game by Goasef")


def playernames():
      # enter players names
     canvas.create_text(83,300,fill="white",font=("Arial", 10, "italic"), text="Enter Player1 name: ")
     canvas.create_text(83,350,fill="white",font=("Arial", 10, "italic"), text="Enter Player2 name: ")

def entry(): #entry
    un_entry = Entry(root, font=("Arial"))
    un1_entry = Entry(root, font=("Arial"))

    un_entry.insert(0, "Player 1")
    un1_entry.insert(0, "player 2")
    
    def entry_clear(e):
        if un_entry.get() == 'Player 1' or un1_entry.get() == 'Player 2':
            un_entry.delete(0,END)
            un1_entry.delete(0,END)
      
    un_entry.bind("<Button-1>", entry_clear)
    un1_entry.bind("<Button-1>", entry_clear)
    
    def sg():
        un1_entry.destroy()
        un_entry.destroy()
        Ok.destroy()
        canvas.create_text(350,350,fill="white",font=("Helvetica", 16, "italic"), text="LET THE GAME BEGIN")


    un_window = canvas.create_window(250, 300, window=un_entry)
    un1_window = canvas.create_window(250, 350, window=un1_entry)
    
    #ok button
    Ok = Button(root, text="Ok!", font=("Arial", 8), width=5, command=sg)
    Ok_window = canvas.create_window(380, 350, window=Ok)

    

#Play Button
Play = Button(text="Play!", lambda: [f() for f in [entry, playernames]])
Play.configure(width=10, activebackground="green", relief=FLAT)
Play_window = canvas.create_window(50,100, window=Play)
Play.pack()

# Quit Button
Quit = Button(text="Quit", command=quit)
Quit.configure(width=10, activebackground="red", relief=FLAT)
Quit_window = canvas.create_window(10,68, window=Quit)
Quit.pack()


canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is telling you exactly what is wrong - you can't have a positional argument after a keyword argument. You simply forgot the `command=` in front of the command.

```
Play = Button(text="Play!", command=lambda: [f() for f in [entry, playernames]]) 
                            ^^^^^^^^
```

Personally, I recommend against using `lambda` in this case. `lambda` just makes the code harder to understand the code and provides nothing in return. The code will be easier to understand and maintain if you use a proper function.

```
def play():
    entry()
    playernames()   
...
Play = Button(text="Play!", command=play)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Play = Button(text="Play!", lambda: [f() for f in [entry, playernames]])
^ SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument.
```

As the error says, you can not pass a positional argument after a keyword argument because it creates ambiguity.

The best fix here will be to pass the command as a keyword argument:

```
Play = Button(text="Play!", command=lambda: [f() for f in [entry, playernames]])
```

On a side note, keep in mind it is a bad practice to use a list (or any other) comprehension for its side-effect. You should consider creating another function that simply calls the other two.